# Comma Separated Values Break Into Second Line

Tags: php

I have a list like:

```
$myList = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
```

I want my list to be displayed as

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far.

Comment: explode by comma -> array chunk by threes, foreach the rows and implode comma with newline in the end, profit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use explode() to brack list to array and print it as you wish

```
$myList = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
$myList_explode = explode(",",$myList);
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($myList_explode);$i++){
 echo $myList_explode[$i];
 if(($i+1)%3==0){
  echo "</br>";
 }else{
   echo ",";
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends what you mean by "displayed", but if you want to echo it to the screen, literally just echo that string to the page and you should get that result (unless the no comma in between 3 and 4 and 6 and 7 is intentional), if not just `echo $mylist`